# Eclipse plugin: How to force it to use a specific version of SWT.jar?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

My eclipse plugin has an external lib that requires SWT 3.75M or above. Therefore I added the corresponding jar file to the class path. Now if I write a test driver to instantiate and call some classes and methods of the lib it works, but if I start my whole plugin and want to call the same methods from there, it doesn't work, because the SWT is below 3.75M

I assume that the problem is, that the plugin does not use the SWT from my lib folder (that I added to the plugin using the appropriate tab in plugin.xml) but the SWT jar from the Eclipse installation. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2):

You should use SWT in your plugin as a bundle/plugin (rather than putting the Jar file in your classpath). And then you can specify when you reference the bundle the minimum version that you require. Do this in the manifest of the plugin that references SWT. You will then need to make sure the desired SWT plugin is available in your target platform.

Comment: ok thanks, but then I get an unsatisfied link constraint. How can I really achieve that the jar is available?

Comment: Did you make sure you added it to your target platform and reload that? (make sure you see the Jar file in the list of files in your target platform) You may need to set up your target platform using a directory instead of installation so that it will pick up all of the jar files and not just the jar files installed into the installation.

Comment: I tried to add the jar file to the target platform, but I'm not able to add a single. Whenever I add the folder the jar is located it, it shows only an empty folder.

Comment: In my target platforms, in the Target Content dialog, in the Locations tab, I clicked "Add",  selected Directory, and then hit the Browse button to select the folder containing the Jars, and then they appeared.

Comment: I did the same, but I can't see them.

Comment: Another approach to try is take an existing target platform and copy them into the plugins directory of that and then load that target platform (using the directory option), they should show up then.